# Mongoengine insert method is not inserting values in db

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb, django-models, mongoengine

I am working on mongoengine with Python3. I am trying to save one user at atime.

```
Users.objects.insert(user, load_bulk=False)
```

Printing this is giving me and ObjectId but still I am not able to see insert data in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just been using the save() method.  You can use it to save and update objects.

```
user = Users(
    parameter1="",
    parameter2="",
    parameter3="")
user.save()
```

To update I'll do this

```
user = User.objects.get(pk='ObjectId goes here')
user.parameter1 = ""
user.parameter2 = ""
user.parameter3 = ""
user.save()
```

Comment: Then that is strange.  I just finished a whole rest api using these methods and everything is working perfectly.  You're not getting any error messages whatsoever?

Comment: You'll have to help others help you.  You need to troubleshoot to narrow down the problem and provide more information.  Check to see if your either sending/receiving the request data wrong, or if you didn't connect to the database correctly.  With this little information, that's the best I can do.

Comment: This was a silly mistake. Problem was that someone wrote table name without using underscore in between and I also did not added table name in model definition.